# Using a flexbox with SVG text and tspan

Tags: css, svg, flexbox

I'm trying to have multiple two-line textboxes positioned nicely, as follows:

[image]

I'd like to do this with a flexbox, so the text would cover the same proportion of the rectangle, no matter how I resize it.  Here's my attempt:

```css
.words text {
  dominant-baseline: text-before-edge;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.words {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
}
rect {
  fill: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect width="300" height="100"></rect>
  <g class="words">
    <text>
      <tspan x="0" y="0">Text</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" y="1.5em">One</tspan>
    </text>
    <text>
      <tspan x="0" y="0">Text</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" y="1.5em">Two</tspan>
    </text>
    <text>
      <tspan x="0" y="0">Text</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" y="1.5em">Three</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uc44jmx1/)

As is plain to see, the text is just bunching up on itself, not spacing evenly like I was hoping would happen.  I am following [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), but I'm not sure if I'm just not understanding how this flex stuff works, or if there's some limitations when it comes to using it with `text`/`tspan`.

How can I use CSS to space these SVG `text` tags evenly over the left half of the rectangle?

Comment: @RobertLongson: Thanks for the definitive answer.  If you post it as such, I'd appreciate it.  If you want to post a work-around, I'd *really* appreciate it!

Comment: You don't seem to need SVG at all here, just use html spans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

display:flex has no effect on SVG content. [display](http://w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#DisplayProperty) none means don't render, any other value than none is treated identically.